# why with look behind regex, the replacement is not working well in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

In Notepad++, for example if the search regex is

```
(?<latex>\$[^\$]*\$)(?=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])
```

and the replace is

```
~\g{latex}~
```

then the replacement is working properly.

But if the search regex contains look behind expression like

```
(?<=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])(?<latex>\$[^\$]*\$)(?=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])
```

then replace

```
~\g{latex}~
```

doesn't work in Notepad++, why???

Comment: Version of notepad++?

Comment: @Jerry notepad++ version v6.6.3

Comment: Does `(?<=\s)\S` match anything? If not then your text editor does not support look-behind.

Comment: @Tomalak notepad++ definitely support look-behind.

Comment: Could you try using `([\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])(?<latex>\$[^\$]*\$)(?=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])` and replace of `$1~\g{latex}~`?

Comment: @Jerry Oddly enough! $1~\g{latex}~ doesn't work in notepad++. It will give result `~g{latex}~` !!! Is it a bug?  But anyway `$1~$2~` works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found out that your named backreference is the actual problem. As per the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions#Substitutions), you need to use the syntax `$+{name}` for a named capture reference in the replace. So that one should work:

```
(?<=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])(?<latex>\$[^\$]*\$)(?=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])
```

And replace with:

```
~$+{latex}~
```

So the first regex you had should not be working properly, but replacing with literal `~g<latex>~`. Even so, I can't really be sure here since I'm using an older version of N++ and the docs could be out of date.

Though I think that the simplest would be that you don't use the capture group. The below should work fine:

```
(?<=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])\$[^$]*\$(?=[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])
```

And replace with `~$0~`.

Comment: Thank you Jerry! I have tried `~$+{latex}~` before, but it didn't work. I know this but since notepad++ 6 support PCRE, I think theoretically `~\g{latex}~` should work without problem, but it is not. What is more, `~$0~` is also not working for my notepad++ version. Have you tested it on your notepad++ version?

Comment: @user15964 Yes, it's working fine. I'm using v6.5.2 though. And while it's PCRE, the replace sure is far from PCRE :) Plus you can use `()` in the replace section without it inserting actual `()`. You have to escape the `()` for them to be literals.

Comment: Oh, I know why now. I found that only `ReplaceAll` will work and `Replace` doesn't work. And you are right, `~\g{latex}~` doesn't work, my mistake. But I didn't understand your last sentence `Plus you can use () in the replace section without it inserting actual (). You have to escape the () for them to be literals`

Comment: @user15964 Try using a replace of `~($+{latex})~` and you'll see no difference. So if you want to put `()` around the latex, you would need `~\($+{latex}\)~`.